# git remote push makes no effect

Tags: git, ssh, repository

I have a shared server(hostgator) which provides me a git client.
I want to update codes on my laptop and send them directly to my shared server.
My problem is that `git` gives me no error message, but it does not change anything.

here is what I did:

On server:

```
serveruser@mydomain.com [~]# git init --bare mycode.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /serverhome/serveruser/mycode.git/
```

On local computer:

```
localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/localuser/path/to/local/code/.git/

localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ git remote add server serveruser@mydomain.com:/serverhome/serveruser/mycode.git

localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ echo '123456'>test;

localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ git add test

localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
[master (root-commit) 5b7ce12] initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test

localuser@localpc:~/path/to/local/code$ git push server master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 209 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To serveruser@mydomain.com:/serverhome/serveruser/mycode.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

Where should I see the `test` file? it is nowhere! neither in `/serverhome/serveruser/` nor in `/serverhome/serveruser/mycode.git`

If I push again I will see this message:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
serveruser@mydomain.com [~]# git init --bare mycode.git
Initialized empty Git repository in /serverhome/serveruser/mycode.git/
```

This is a *bare repository*. You can use it as a remote and push to it, like you did, but it's not meant for working in it and browsing files.

You can clone from your bare repository on the server and use that clone to see the files in it, for example:

```
git clone mycode.git mycode
```

Keep in mind that after you push from your local pc, you will have to do `git pull` in your clone so it gets the changes from `mycode.git`. The bare repo will be a common remote for both your local repo and the clone.

If you want to automatically update the clone on the server every time you pushed to it, you can create a `post-receive` hook. I wrote an article on that [on my blog](http://www.janosgyerik.com/deploying-new-releases-using-git-and-the-post-receive-hook/).

Comment: Thanks for important points. So, if I want to avoid, using shell of server and push directly from local path to server, What should I do?

Comment: You want to setup a `post-receive` hook so that when you do a `git push` from local, the script will do a `git pull` in `mycode` (the non-bare clone of `mycode.git`).

Comment: i have a problem. when in shell of server I type `git clone mycode.git /serverhome/serveruser`

I face with this error: `fatal: destination path '/serverhome/serveruser' already exists and is not an empty directory.`

Any way to overwrite items in user home directory of server?

Comment: You *could* do this but I don't think it's a good idea: `git init; git remote add origin mycode.git; git pull`

Answer (score 0):

The file is actually pushed, but you are looking for it in the wrong way, you can clone the git folder on the server then checkout master

Comment: may you tell exacly what to type in terminal(and which terminal, terminal of server or local computer)?